# How to handle a non-SOAP error message? "Response did not arrive for request"

Tags: c#, wcf, sap-xi

I have a WCF client for a set of services in an SAP system. For certain errors, the services are (allegedly) unable to return a SOAP fault. Instead I receive something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jpr:Fault xmlns:jpr="http://com.sap/aii/proxy/xiruntime/">com.sap.aii.proxy.xiruntime.core.ESPXISystemFaultException: Error encountered during processing of XI request message in inbound ESP; Hint: com.sap.engine.interfaces.webservices.runtime.RuntimeProcessException: Response did not arrive for request 8d4b2782-062a-11e6-b0f9-0000193763e3</jpr:Fault>
```

The above represents a certain type of timeout in the service. The only piece of information I have available here to identify it as a timeout, is this piece of text:

> Response did not arrive for request

There are WSDLs but the vendor doesn't take them very seriously. I've also asked to try and give me a SOAP fault, but they insist it isn't possible in this case.

How can I handle a message like this? Currently, I receive this exception chain:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Unrecognized message version.
```

Comment: Handle it how?   Putting the call to the service in a try-catch block and handling the exception would seem to be the easiest way.

Comment: @Tim catching a TargetInvocationException is too broad, I must ensure that I only catch this specific message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you will have to work with some low level bits. The place you want to be is in the client channel where you can install your component in the channel for handling this kind of response. Take a look at [WCF Extensibility – Channels](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/07/11/wcf-extensibility-channels/) where you can find how to create your protocol channel.

After that you can create your Custom Binding stacking up channels where you have Transport (must be present), Your protocol, Encoder, etc...

Comment: There are many ways to handle the error. If you want to return something to the client as a meaningful message instead of Unrecognized Version.

Comment: Sure, but in this case it seems a simple try-catch would do the trick, rather than going to the trouble of writing a custom binding.

Comment: I figured it wouldn't be easy. Our team has already decided it isn't worth the effort, so I won't be spending time for verifying your suggestion, but thank you for the info nevertheless.